# SSRS Drillthrough server report error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportviewer, report, drillthrough

I have a SSRS report with an action on a text-box.
Go to report property is set to the parent report so this makes the parent report also a drillthrough report for itself.
I deployed the report on the report server and it is rendered ok and also the drillthrough action works ok in the Report Manager.
When I attach this report to a ReportViewer control in an .aspx the parent report is rendered ok but the drillthrough action causes an error (Invalid argument).
I have 2 visible and 3 hidden parameters for this report.
I tried to override the ReportViewerCtrl_Drillthrough event and added the following code:

```
ReportViewerCtrl.ServerReport.SetParameters(reportParamList);
ReportViewerCtrl.ServerReport.Refresh();
```

where reportParamList is a list of parameters passed from the parent report to the drillthrough report but I get the same error (I used DrillthroughEventArgs.Report.GetParameters() to get the list of parameters and they're passed by in a correct way). 
I didn't find on other forums something like this related to reports deployed on Server Report (only for local report).

Any idea would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

I have found the issue for this. 
It was related to the way .aspx page was built. 
My report viewer control was framed by a form tag but it appears it also needed a  table tag too. 
So this is how my .aspx page looks now: 
table 
tr 
td 
form 
ReportViewer Control 
/form  
/td 
/tr 
/table